# generate file from bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, heredoc

I have to generate a file.sql file, in which I want to hold some DDL statements.

Firstly it should create a database user, schema and grant some permissions. Then it should make copyes of some tables into newly created schema. Table names I hold in bash array variable. Number of tables in array may vary.

I cannot make **one** `cat > file.sql < EOF ... EOF` block to do that, because I need to generate CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE commands.. depends on the table count.

I made a generate.sh script with variables and three bash functions:

```
TABLES=( "table_one" "table_two" "table_three" "table_four" "table_five")
SOURCE_SCHEMA="src"
TARGET_SCHEMA="tgt"
FILE=file.sql
```

```
function create_prepare_sql_v1 {
   cat > $FILE << EOF_SQL_V1

...here goes create user/schema and grant statements...

EOF_SQL_V1
```

```
function create_prepare_sql_v2 {
count=1
for table in ${!TABLES[@]}; do
        ( echo -e "CREATE TABLE $SOURCE_SCHEMA.${TABLES[$table]} AS TABLE $TARGET_SCHEMA.${TABLES[$table]};" \
        "\nALTER TABLE $SOURCE_SCHEMA.${TABLES[$table]} ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);" \
        "\nINSERT INTO $SOURCE_SCHEMA.temp VALUES ("$count", '"$TARGET_SCHEMA"', '"${TABLES[$table]}"');" ) >> $FILE
        ((count++))
done
```

```
function create_prepare_sql_v3 {
   cat >> $FILE << 'EOF_SQL_V3'

...here I put my custom PL/pgSQL functions...

EOF_SQL_V3
```

When I execute the functions and I check that file.sql has allprevious data by adding and removing step#_done strings. When all done, I remove step_3_done string.

It works but seems, that this is a very weak solution.

```
create_prepare_sql_v1 && echo "step1_done" >> $FILE || exit 1
create_prepare_sql_v2 && sed -i 's/step1_done/step2_done/' $FILE || exit 1
create_prepare_sql_v3 && sed -i 's/step2_done/step3_done/' $FILE || exit 1


if ! fgrep -q 'step3_done' $FILE ; then
        echo "Something went wrong. Exiting.."
        exit 1
fi

sed -i '/step3_done/d' $FILE
echo "All good."
```

After generation the file.sql should be something like that:

```
\connect dbname
CREATE USER u_user WITH PASSWORD 'blah';
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS src AUTHORIZATION u_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA src TO u_user;

CREATE TABLE src.temp (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    schema_name VARCHAR(100),
    table_name VARCHAR(100),
    truncated BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);

CREATE TABLE src.table_one AS TABLE tgt.table_one;
ALTER TABLE src.table_one ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
INSERT INTO src.temp VALUES (1, 'tgt', 'table_one');

CREATE TABLE src.table_two AS TABLE tgt.table_two;
ALTER TABLE src.table_two ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
INSERT INTO src.temp VALUES (2, 'tgt', 'table_two');

CREATE TABLE src.table_three AS TABLE tgt.table_three;
ALTER TABLE src.table_three ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
INSERT INTO src.temp VALUES (3, 'tgt', 'table_three');
etc

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ..
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ..
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ..
```

If it was only sql statements with constant number of tables, there would be no problem to do that with one `cat > $FILE << EOF <some_code> EOF` block...

Can you plese offer a better solution? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal? to copy one schema to another? To do a dump of the database? There are many ways to do it without bash with pg_dump or plain SQL but it's not clear what is it you want to do. Also, the schema is in the same database or another?

Comment: My goal is to create a plain file with sql statements. The problem is that I wish to do it with `cat > $FILE << EOF ... EOF` block but inside that I cannot use `for loop` to generate `CREATE`, `INSERT`, `ALTER` statements... When file is created I run master bash script wich runs sql statements from generated file `psql -f "$FILE"`. It should prepare my database for further work. All is done in one database.

Comment: My plan is to create unified solution for company DBAs - take scripts and run on your own db instance. With my solution, after executing one bash function I need to check if file.sql has all needed statements (doing it with `sed` string replacement). Then exec another bash function ... and another check. If file do not have some sql statements, for example if one bash func fails.. I do not want to feed that file to `psql`. I wish to do that more intelligently that I have at the moment.

Comment: If it's only for postgreSQL, it would be much easer with a PL function since you have access to the database schemas. With a PL you can create the .sql file, ready to run. But if it is meant for any DBMS, then I would recomend a bash aproach or other.